# Calling api from django view error. forbidden (csrf token is missing or incorrect)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I seen alot of other solution, tried it but problem still persist.

When i do a requests.get, it works fine but when i'm doing requests.post. I got this forbidden (csrf token is missing or incorrect) error.

Here is my code

**models.py**

```
class TestPost(models.Model):
    # reminderId = models.AutoField()
    book = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class TestPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # valid_time_formats = ['%H:%M', '%I:%M%p', '%I:%M %p']
    # time = serializers.TimeField(format='%I:%M %p', input_formats=valid_time_formats, allow_null=True)
    date = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p")

    class Meta:
        model = TestPost
        fields = ('id', 'book', 'author', 'date')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import requests

def my_django_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/', params=request.POST)
    else:
        r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/', params=request.GET)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return HttpResponse('Yay, it worked')
    return HttpResponse('Could not save data')

class TestPostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = TestPost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestPostSerializer
```

I did a POST method on the url of the function but error

Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /test/
[22/Jan/2018 16:59:09] "POST /test/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2502

Comment: "I did a POST method on the url of the function but error" <-- how do you do this? If you are using `SessionAuthentication` you need to pass a valid CSRF token as described in http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/#csrf-protection.

Comment: Ah, that url is from my local project. I have 2 different django project , P1 and P2. I am using P1 to call P2 api using postman.